# Outputting contents of list into three separate files

Tags: python, list, output, typeerror

I got two outside files that I already combined into a alphabetically sorted list and I need to output all names in the ranges A-I, J-R and S-Z to three different .txt files.

```
# Send names beginning with A-I to new file.
for x in names:
    if names[x] == ["A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I"]:
            print('babyNamesAtoI.txt', file=f)
# Send names beginning with J-R to new file.
    elif names[x] == ["J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O", "P", "Q", "R"]:
        print('babyNamesJtoR.txt', file=f)
# Send names beginning with S-Z to new file.
else:
      print('babyNamesStoZ', file=f)
```

Every time I run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Babynamesort.py", line 37, in <module>
    if names[x] == ["A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I"]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is an element of `names`, so saying `names[x]` does not make any sense.  If you want to match against the first letter, do `if x[0] in "ABCDEFGHI":`.  However, the "print" statement doesn't do what you think it does, either.  I THINK you want:

```
f1 = open("babyNamesAtoI.txt","w")
f2 = open("babyNamesJtoR.txt","w")
f3 = open("babyNamesStoZ.txt","w")
for name in names:
    if name[0] in "ABCDEFGHI":
        print( name, file=f1 )
    elif name[0] in "JKLMNOPQR":
        print( name, file=f2 )
    else:
        print( name, file=f3 )
```

Comment: This solved my issue with creating the files but none of the names show up in them.

Edit -  I forgot to add .close() at the end and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with

```py
if names[x] == ["A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I"]:
```

that's not really Python syntax. A solution could be to take advantage of comparing strings with mathematical operators.

```py
f1 = open('babyNamesAtoI.txt', 'w')
f2 = open('babyNamesJtoR.txt', 'w')
f3 = open('babyNamesStoZ.txt', 'w')

for name in names:
    if (name >= "A" and name < "J"):
        f1.write(name)
    elif (name >= "J" and name < "S"):
        f2.write(name)
    else
        f3.write(name)

f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```